# HTML pattern in input text was not working (one minus and decimal)

Tags: html, regex, angular, validation

I am currently working on regex with my current regex where I can able to restrict user.

I have checked with regextester.com with this pattern

This won't work

```
+10
e10
^([-,0-9.]+)
```

this will work

```
-10
-10.00
10.00
```

But when I try to put in html input (number) this was not working.

```
<input  style="width: 65px;" pattern="^([-,0-9.]+)" type="text">
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you specify a case in which the check fails and the base logic of your regex (what kind of check are you doing)?

Comment: @WoAiNii thanks for your reply 

user can enter -10.00

 -1.0 but user should not enter +10.0 and +10  and e10

Comment: To manage decimal you can add `step=0.01`, if you need only 2 decimals. To manage + an option is using js, like explained [here](To manage decimal you can add `step=0.01`, if you need only 2 decimals. To manage + an option is using js, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777762/html5-input-type-number-not-prevent-plus-minus-symbols) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777762/html5-input-type-number-not-prevent-plus-minus-symbols), sorry but the pattern seems to be ignored), sorry but the pattern seems to be ignored

Comment: Or you can think about using a generic input field and then use pattern, something like this `<input pattern="^(-?[0-9]{0,2}([.,][0-9]{0,2})?)$">` (adapting it as needed)

Comment: @WoAiNii i am trying the last point which you said

Comment: Here ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern)) you can see why the pattern is ignored, with type number

Comment: @WoAiNii yes trying with text only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212591/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-woainii).

Answer (score -2):

The html pattern attribute doesn't designed for number. So you can change your type either text or tel.

Comment: Describe More Details With Some Code Which you have tried For Your Issue